# why does g++ add includes differently within makefile?

Tags: makefile, g++, include

I am new to make files and having an issue where the g++ command works when run on the command line but not within a make file. The following line works:

```
g++ -I/home/user/ml/dynet/dynet -I/home/user/ml/dynet main.cpp
```

but the following make file can't find the required header file

```
ai: main.o
        g++ -I/home/user/ml/dynet/dynet -I/home/user/ml/dynet main.cpp
```

the main.cpp is simple

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dynet.h"
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

when I run the make I get the error that it can't fine the

```
user@LAPTOP-AUOAPRL1:~/ml/ai$ make
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: dynet.h: No such file or directory
 #include "dynet.h"
```

Why would the same line run differently? where is it looking when run within make? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Make in it's infinite wisdom has chosen to use it's built-in rules. You can run without them by `make --no-builtin-rules`. It's not nice to have that as a prerequisite for building your files, but it might be useful when debugging "strange behavior" as it proves whether it's the built-in rules interfering with your mental model or not.

As for the wisdom itself, you only say how to build `ai` from `main.o` - not how to build `main.o`. That is what you're seeing - the built-in rule for building `main.o`.

What I think you want to do instead is have the rule like this:

```
ai: main.cpp
    g++ ...
```

---

A tip; you should prefer using the built-in rules and variables, as it makes the makefile a little simpler to manage:

```
# using built-in variables
CC := g++
CPPFLAGS := -I/home/user/ml/dynet/dynet -I/home/user/ml/dynet

# inspired by built-in rules
ai: main.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html

Comment: Thank you! switching it to main.cpp worked. Also --no-builtin-rules when it was still left as main.o worked. I will do some reading to understand why!

Comment: There is no built-in rule that will match the target `ai: main.o`.  You will have to provide a recipe for that.  Make knows how to build an executable from an object which uses the same prefix: so you could use either `ai: ai.o` or `main: main.o` to use make's built-in rules, but you can't use `ai: main.o`

Comment: @MadScientist Oh dear, got it mixed up with something else... Updating answer. From https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html: *In more complicated cases, such as when there is no object file whose name derives from the executable file name, you must write an explicit recipe for linking.*

Comment: In your recipe you need to add `-o $@` as well...